# How to open word or pdf from web inf folder in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, jboss, web-inf

I have a requirement there is a userguide link in the search page.When the user clicks link need to download the Word or PDF document from WEB-INF\doc folder in the WAR which is deployed in JBOSS.

In the Search Page there is an link as below
Download PDF File 
Once click the link User guide document should download from the WEB-INF\doc folder and open

After search google I found  we need to use like this

```
InputStream resourceContent = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/doc/foo.doc");
```

My application used JSP and Servlet as a controller in that case do I need to write the below code in doGet method

// gets MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(filePath);
        if (mimeType == null) {
            // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

```
    // modifies response
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

    // forces download
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // obtains response's output stream
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
```

Also what I need to configure in WEB.XML.

My understand is when click the link call the Servelt doGet method to download.

Could you please help on this what are the steps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, implement the logic in the `HttpServlet.doGet()` method

When I was dealing with similar requirement (back in 2008) I used this method to set correct HTTP headers for downloading (`attachment=true`) or direct displaying (`attachment=false`) documents:

```java
public static void setDownloadHeaders(HttpServletResponse aRes,
    String aContentType, String aName, boolean anAttachment) {
  if (aRes == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "HttpServletResponse can't be null.");
  }
  aRes.setContentType(aContentType);
  StringBuffer tmpCd = new StringBuffer(anAttachment ? "attachment;" : 
    "inline;");
  if (aName != null) {
    tmpCd.append(" filename=\"").append(aName).append("\";");
  }
  aRes.setHeader("Content-Disposition", tmpCd.toString());
  aRes.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
  aRes.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
}
```

You have to choose correctly the content type. In my case for directly displaying PDFs it was:

```
setDownloadHeaders(response, "application/pdf", getPdfFileName(), false);
```

You don't need to configure anything special in `web.xml`. Everything should work for you.